# Get relational data ordered

Tags: php, oop, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony2 project using Doctrine2 how to get relational data ordered by some parameters? For example: there are two related entities, Articles and Comments. Doctrine generated the following method:

```
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comment;
}
```

When I run this `$article->getComments()` it gives comments of that article. Now I want comments to be ordered by, let say, date, popularity, etc. In other words, I want to write some methods such as `$article->getCommentsOrderedByDate()` but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP usort function can be used for customized sorting that goes beyond Doctrine's built in sorting capability which @elnur has linked to.

Simple example which can go right into your entity class.

```
public function getTeams() 
{ 
    $teams = $this->teams->toArray();

    usort($teams,array($this,'compareEventTeams'));

    return $teams; 
}
public function compareEventTeams($team1,$team2)
{
    if ($team1->getType() == 'Home') return -1;
    if ($team2->getType() == 'Home') return  1;
    return strcmp($team1->getType(),$team2->getType());
}
```

EDITED:  Just noticed that passing the array to be sorted using & appears to be depreciated so I dropped it from my post.  Still works fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [*Ordering To-Many Associations*](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html).